# Bootstrap3, I want to make this not be piled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**CODE**

```css
<style type="text/css">
            .nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus .navbar-header>a:hover, .navbar-header>a:focus {
                background-color: #7F613F;
            }
         a   .icon-color {
                color: #282828;
            }
        </style>
```

```html
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #b39369">
        <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-header">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment icon-color"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt icon-color"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-color"></i></a></li>
     </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

As you can see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjzeysw7/), as the browser narrows, above three icons are piled up, as if there are 3 navbars.

But i want maintaining only one navbar floor with these 3 icons appearing.

How can i modify this piling?

Comment: "Just use Flex" :) Actually, you can just retain the inherit positioning and layout by declaring `.nav > li {float: left}` at the media *max-width* breakpoint of `768px` (`@media(max-width: 768px)`)

Comment: You should correct your HTML first. For example, you are using `<li>` but have specified no ordered or unordered list.  That tag should not exist outside a `<ol>` or `<ul>` parent.

Comment: @JustuseFlex I'm thankful of your good answer and your answers works well. But can i ask more when i added a navbar-collapse toggle, it crashed a little. Icons are attached to left very closely and navbar's height is changed very little taller. jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mjzeysw7/7/ Would you help me more? sorry.